# thunderbird stuck with 'Status: Creating mail message...'

Tags: 16.04, thunderbird, enigmail

the last update of thunderbird (the version is now `52.1.1 (64-bit)`) on ubuntu 16.04 causes my mail client to get stuck with the message

> Status: Creating mail message...

then nothing happens anymore. i can cancel but not send the mail again... this happens often. i then have to start a new message and try again until the message is sent.

is there a fix for that? is that a bug? i have not changed anything in the configuration of the mail accounts since the update.

---

update: as [Debora Weber-Wulff](https://askubuntu.com/users/692467/debora-weber-wulff) pointed out this may be an [enigmail](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/enigmail/) related issue only. (confirmed!)

---

update: there is a [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/enigmail/bugs/687/) for enigmail.

Comment: Same thing here, but on a Mac OSX 10.11.6. Just one account (that uses Enigmail) has the same behavior. I can send encrypted emails from other accounts with no problem, but for this account (posteo.de) it just hangs.

Comment: @DeboraWeber-Wulff: it may very well be that this is enigmail related. i don't think i have ever seen it happen with contacts i do not use gpg for... thanks!

Comment: I have this problem as well on MacOS. I found that there are `gpg` processes running in the background. If I kill those processes, tb immediately crashes. This is definitely an interaction between tb/enigmail/gpg.

Comment: And I can send unencrypted emails from the posteo account without problem. I can also accept encrypted emails at the posteo account and decrypt them without problem. So it seems to be a general Thunderbird/Enigmail/GPG interaction, not so much an Ubuntu problem. Now, where do we find help? ;)

Comment: Just found a bizarre workaround: save the email in the drafts folder by selecting that from the menu. Then it will send just fine....

Comment: I'm experincing exactly the same issue since I've recently updated Thunderbird in my Ubuntu 16.04. What I have seen is that even if it cannot send the message, after cancelling you can still save the draft and then I can try again sending the draft.

Comment: @DavidFoerster `-safe-mode` disables enigmail... did not try `thunderbird 55`.  but thanks for the hint!

Comment: Yes, add-ons are disabled in safe mode; that's the whole point. You said you had not confirmed whether this is related to Enigmail. Also, Enigmail may be incompatible with or buggy in pre-release builds of Thunderbird.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: i am pretty certain by now that it is enigmail related. sorry, should have stated that more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the developer of enigmail has released a new [pre-release (`1.9.8-a4`) of enigmail](https://enigmail.net/download/beta/enigmail-1.9.8-a4.xpi); as [announced in a post](https://sourceforge.net/p/enigmail/bugs/687/?limit=25&page=1#8321) on the bug tracker.

the bug has never shown up in this version.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it appears to be this bug: [#687 Enigmail hanging on send - Thunderbird 52.1.1](https://sourceforge.net/p/enigmail/bugs/687/)

### Work-around

One suggested work-around (confirmed by multiple bug report commentators) is to kill all GPG processes,

```
killall gpg gpg2
```

and try again.

### Beta-version with fix

You can also install [the pre-release version `1.9.8-a3` of Enigmail](https://enigmail.net/download/beta/enigmail-1.9.8-a3.xpi) that's supposed to contain a fix.

Comment: the prerelease `1.9.8-a3` has worked several days without a glitch so far! thanks.

Comment: argh! and right now the bug reappeared with the pre-release version...

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem but my work-around is just to click on the 'X' to close the compose window, then choose the option to save the draft. Then open, edit and send the draft and it has always then gone without any further problems.

I also changed the location of my drafts folder to a local folder because prior to that I ended up with lots of encrypted 'drafts' that had to be manually deleted as each draft, when encrypted, was unique. With a local drafts folder the drafts are unencrypted and are deleted automatically when sent.

Comment: I changed the location to local as well and updated to 1.9.8.1 (soon to be 1.9.8.4?), works now.